# Mapping not working in gazebo, /scan messages published on wrong topic

Tags: gazebo, ros2, slam, ros-humble, laserscan

I am pretty new to gazebo and am currently trying to simulate my physical robot. I have already created a world and am now trying to create a map for it. I am using [this repository](https://github.com/igrak34/turtlebot2-ros2/tree/humble-devel/turtlebot2_gazebo)  for all the launch files aswell as [this repository for the kobuki description](https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros). I have modified the kobuki_ros/kobuki_description/urdf/kobuki_gazebo.urdf.xacro file in the last line and added

```
      <gazebo reference="hokuyo_link">
<sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <visualize>false</visualize>
  <update_rate>40</update_rate>
  <ray>
    <scan>
      <horizontal>
        <samples>720</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
        <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
      </horizontal>
    </scan>
    <range>
      <min>0.10</min>
      <max>30.0</max>
      <resolution>0.01</resolution>
    </range>
    <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <!-- Noise parameters based on published spec for Hokuyo laser
           achieving "+-30mm" accuracy at range < 10m.  A mean of 0.0m and
           stddev of 0.01m will put 99.7% of samples within 0.03m of the true
           reading. -->
      <mean>0.0</mean>
      <stddev>0.01</stddev>
    </noise>
  </ray>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
    <topicName>/tb2/scan</topicName>
    <frameName>hokuyo_link</frameName>
  </plugin>
  </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

Whenever I try to launch the `turtlebot2_slam.launch.py`, the world opens aswell as rviz2, but rviz2 cannot find the fixed frame (map) and adding all LaserScan topics in rviz2 wont show me any marks in rviz2. Ive checked rqt_graph which looks like this:
[image]
and rqt is showing that the only messages received for this topic type are for /tb2/scan. I know that i somehow need to publish the messages on to /scan but changing the topic name in the modified part of kobuki_gazebo.urdf.xacro from /tb2/scan to /scan does not change anything. Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can do 3 things:

- change the configuration of slam to listen the specific topic of tb2/scan in the [slam configuration params](https://github.com/igrak34/turtlebot2-ros2/blob/humble-devel/turtlebot2_gazebo/config/slam_toolbox_params.yaml)
- remap the topic when slam is launched to listen /tb2/scan instead scan.
- remap the topic when turtlebot is launched to publish in /scan instead on /tb2/scan

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I forgot to add that I have already tried the first option  and it didnt work. As for the second and third option there are only a few nodes in the launch file, in which node do I need to remap? (turtlebot2_slam.launch.py=Nodes: rviz2,async_slam_toolbox_node; turtlebot2_spawn_robot.launch.py=Nodes: robot_state_publisher,spawn_entity.py)

Comment: I would think it would also be possible to change the line in the xacro file: ` <topicName>/tb2/scan</topicName>` to be ` <topicName>/scan</topicName>` or just remove it entirely if the default topic for Hokuyo is "/scan." But if there's something else trying to publish on that topic, then there will be conflicts.

Comment: And as for remapping, you need to remap either the publisher or all the subscribers so they are all looking at the same topic name.

Comment: @proan I have tried to change the line already but sadly it didnt work for some reason. Do you mean to remove the topicName line or the whole added part?

Comment: I was thinking remove the topicName section, but I find it interesting that just changing it doesn't seem to work.

For the remapping, you've already got rqt_graph going, so you can use that to sort it all out, hopefully.

Comment: @DJ1NN I think slam is using the slam package configuration called 'mapper_params_online_async.yaml'. You can change that file, change the path of the 'slam_params_file' default to os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(
        'turtlebot2_gazebo'), 'config', 'slam_toolbox_params.yaml'), or just launch with parameter 'slam_params_file' with the path of 'slam_toolbox_params.yaml'.
The most recommended is the last one, just need the path of the params to be used.

Comment: @rdelgadov I have tried to launch it with the parameter but it still doesnt work. I have also compared the "mapper_params_online_async.yaml"-file and the "slam_toolbox_params.yaml"-file and they have the same scan_topic. I think the problem lays in the namespace, since /tb2/turtlebot2_laserscan is publishing on /tb2/scan when it should be publishing on /scan. I have searched for the "turtlebot2_laserscan"-Node and only found "protected:
 sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::ConstSharedPtr scan) override;
" in slam_toolbox/include/slam_toolbox/slam_toolbox_async.hpp

Comment: Do you maybe know how to bypass the namespace for the launchfile?

Comment: Hi @DJ1NN! I have seen that you solve with the help of proan, can you share the solution? or better, can you made a pr or a fork of the repo with the solution to anybody can use it?.

Comment: Hello @rdelgadov! Basically the solution was to remove the topic name in the xacro file for the hokuyo ASWELL as changing the topic in my world file that I have created for the turtlebot2_laserscan link to /scan aswell. The problem now is, that its publishing on the right topic when I use turtlebot2_slam.launch.py but not when I am launching turtlebot2_nav2.launch.py since the launch file is using the tb2 namespace and replacing the /scan topic with ${robot_namespace}/scan is unfortuantely not working.

Comment: And for some reason it not mapping when I use the turtlebot2_slam.launch.py but rather showing me the laserscan marks (when I add the map topic it says, that no map is received)

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to see that topic remapping wasn't working, but it looks like the launch files have been written to enable multiple Turtlebots and spawning each one within its own namespace. Each set of topics is remapped by the launch files away from their defaults in the global namespace.

It looks like you can set `use_namespace = false` on [Line 19 of your launch file](https://github.com/igrak34/turtlebot2-ros2/blob/dccfe89e18c7414fd7ee280f1501d0703c4ad4bc/turtlebot2_gazebo/launch/turtlebot2_slam.launch.py#L19) and edit your xacro file so you're publishing on "/scan": `<topicName>/scan</topicName>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But isnt use_namespace = false already set in line 41?

Comment: It sure looks like that, and at least for the slam_toolbox topics they are in the global namespace. Somehow your laser scan is not in the global namespace though, and that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea on how to bring the /tb2 topic to the global namespace? Maybe somehow remap in the launch file?

Comment: You should be able to remap in the launch file, yes.

The `turtlebot2_slam.launch.py` eventually runs the Kobuki xacro files in `turtlebot2_spawn_robot_launch.py`, but it looks like `turtlebot2_world.launc.py` does not pass along that `use_namespace = false` from the `turtlebot2_slam.launch.py`. See if your changes starting at Line 83 <https://github.com/igrak34/turtlebot2-ros2/blob/dccfe89e18c7414fd7ee280f1501d0703c4ad4bc/turtlebot2_gazebo/launch/turtlebot2_world.launch.py#L83> result in the change you desire.

Comment: The problem is, whenever I launch the turtlebot2_nav2.launch.py and check the rqt_graph, nearly every node/topic is in the tb2 namespace and connected (the /tb2/scan aswell). Doesnt that mean, that the turtlebot2_world.launch.py is working fine and that there should be changes in the turtlebot2_slam.launch.py-file?

Comment: But there are also problems with rviz2 when the turtlebot2_nav2.launch.py is launched. It shows me that the fixed frame (map) does not exist, even when I am trying to set an estimated pose (I am using the default map which comes with the repository in connection with my world)

Comment: You'll have to use rqt_graph to debug your system. If slam_toolbox is publishing at "/map", and RViz says it doesn't exist, it means slam_toolbox hasn't published a map yet, probably because it hasn't received any laser scans. If slam_toolbox is publishing to "/tb2/map", then you should point RViz to that as your fixed frame.

The nested launch files are troublesome to debug here, but you need to make sure your graph is properly connected.

Comment: In rqt_graph it does look properly connected with map_server. I have checked rqts topic monitor and saw that all topic with type /nav2_msgs/actions/ have the value: "cannot get message class for type "/nav2_msgs/actions/...""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151063/discussion-between-proan-and-dj1nn).